# Getting null pointer exception while passing value from Activity to service

Tags: android, service, android-intent

In Activity i have passed a value paramVal like this

```
 Intent srv = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
    startService(srv);

     //Intent intent =new Intent("com.example.firstapplication.STARTACTIVITY"); 
     //intent.putExtra("myFirstKey", paramVal); 

    //intent.putExtra("myFirstKey", paramVal); 

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putCharSequence("myFirstKey", paramVal);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and in service I am retrieving a value like this

```
 @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onStart(intent, startId);

      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      data = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("myFirstKey");

      System.out.println("data checking"+data);
     }
```

but i am getting null pointer exception for the line

```
data = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("myFirstKey");
```

in service

should i have to call onstart method in service somewhere. Please let me know where is the problem??

Comment: see this http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/pass-data-from-activity-to-service.html tuts for passing data from Activity to Serivce and also as in your current code you are starting Service before putting value in intent so start it after preparing intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity:

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
lIntent.putExtra("myFirstKey", <your String param here>);
startService(lIntent);
```

In your Service:

```
String lDataString = intent.getStringExtra("myFirstKey");
```

As a sidenote:

- please override onStartCommand() in your service, since onStart() is deprecated
- it is not required to call super.onStartCommand() (or super.onStart() for that matter) when extending the Service class

Answer (score 0):

You're starting the service before passing the extras...

Comment: ok so should i write like this  Intent srv = new Intent(this, TestService.class);

 
 

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putCharSequence("myFirstKey", paramVal);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);     startService(srv);

Answer (score 0):

It might work, you are changing the order of instruction. the service is starting before inserting values in the intent.

```
Intent srv = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putCharSequence("myFirstKey", paramVal);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
startService(srv);
```